# Deflatestream - end of stream reached before parsing was completed

Tags: c#, filestream, compression, deflatestream

I try to write a List to a FileStream. Since the object was too big, I split the list in evenly distributed chunks, and append it to the FileStream with a DeflateStream to compress the data. This all works fine.

However if I try to do the same to decompress it, it gives an error: 'reached the end of the stream before parsing was completed'. This is the code to decompress:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)) {
    using (DeflateStream ds = new DeflateStream(fs, CompressionMode.Decompress, true)) {
        //Deserialize offerte
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        //Check position
        while (ds.BaseStream.Position < ds.BaseStream.Length) {
            result.AddRange((List<User>)bf.Deserialize(ds));
        }
    }
}
```

What I notice is that the first chunk of users is nicely being written to result. However when it should start on the second chunk of users it gives an error right away (It seems before even trying to get the second chunk). What can I do about this or is wrong?

@Edit 10:43 - 16-10-2015 Additional remark

If I skip the DeflateStream and only use FileStream, then it works like a charm.

Compress method (I call this function x times, every chunk once):

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Append)) {
    using (DeflateStream cs = new DeflateStream(fs, CompressionMode.Compress)) {
        //Serialize offerte
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(cs, offerte);
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently, you're not compressing properly. Do you close/dispose of `DeflateStream` when serializing?

Comment: @AntonGogolev I added the compression method. I call this code for each chunk of the list.

Comment: Oh, now I see where the problem likely is. In your serialization code, move chunk iteration logic _inside_ the `using(DeflateStream...)` part

Comment: Yeah, now you say it is makes sense. The length of the file is probably written in the header and when you create the file with the first chunk. It already has a fixed length? Or am I saying something absolutely crazy?

Comment: After serialization, your data goes like this: `DEFLATE_HEADER DATA DEFLATE_HEADER DATA` ..., but you attempt to deserialize it as if it were `DEFLATE_HEADER DATA DATA ...`, which throws `BinaryFormatter` off